# kubectl port-forward not binding the IPv4 loopback address 127.0.0.1

Tags: localhost, port, kubectl, portforwarding, ipv4

Running the following command on `Ubuntu 20.04`:

```
kubectl port-forward -n some-namespace service/some-service 9900:5432
```

and the output is only:

```
Forwarding from [::1]:9900 -> 5432
```

That is, it is only forwarding from the IPv6 loopback address and not IPv4.

Verified that this issue isn't related to the firewall rules.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Could you post the output of `netstat -ntlp | grep 9900` ?

Comment: Right, so I run that and a process known to me was indeed using this port 9900... Tried again after killing the process and now it works... Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/<service-name> 9900:5432
```

or

```
kubectl port-forward --address 127.0.0.1 service/<service-name> 9900:5432
```

if you're interested only to port forward on *localhost* adress.

#### Update:

As I mentioned in comments:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep 9900
```

will tell you whether this port is already in use, but if you give a try to the above example, you would also obtain the same information.

Just let me explain on a simple example what really happened here.

To illustrate it I deployed a simple `nginx` pod and exposed it via `ClusterIP` service.

If I try to run `kubectl port-forward` now, everything works as expected:

```
$ kubectl port-forward -n default service/static-web 8080:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80
```

But let's open a new tab and run `netcat` which will listen on port `8080`:

```
nc -l 8080
```

If we try to run `kubectl port-forward` now, the result is similar to the one in your example:

```
$ kubectl port-forward -n default service/static-web 8080:80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80
```

i.e. only **IPv6** is being used and there is no error message. Why is this happening ? Well, if you don't explicitly specify the address in `kubectl port-forward` command, it will try to use something that is available. As long as it can successfully bind to **IPv6** loopback, `port-forward` operation can be performed successfully and there is no error message.

However if we specify explicitly that we're interested only in using **IPv4**, we'll see quite descriptive error, telling us exactly what's going on:

```
$ kubectl port-forward --address 127.0.0.1 -n default service/static-web 8080:80
Unable to listen on port 8080: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:8080: bind: address already in use]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{8080 80}]
```

As you can see, it also tells us that port `8080` is already in use:

```
[unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:8080: bind: address already in use]
```

Comment: The issue was related to a port being already in use, as hinted at by your previous comment, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out the port 9900 was already in use. To solve this issue:

Run:

`netstat -ntlp | grep 9900`

Find the PID of the process listening on this port and kill it by running:

`kill -9 <PID>`

Now it should work.